# Understanding the static $_class variable declaration in codeigniter load_class function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was going through the core functionalities of CodeIgniter and I have a doubt with the declaration of the variable

```
static $_classes = array();
```

[as pointed out by this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12018280/5170117), the variable is to cache the class objects.

My doubt is because the variable is declared inside the function scope,

is it not supposed to get initialised every time a call to the load_class function is made?

**should the function be like this**

```
static $_classes = array();  //declared outside the scope
function load_class (@prams-----) {
  // inner workings
}
```

**instead of**

```
function load_class(@params---) {
  static $_class = array();  // declared inside the scope
  //inner workings
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120767/static-variables-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static), static variables are (only) initialized at the *first call* of the function.